# Why does ETH and BNB(or BSC) coins have same coin number on derivation path at ioncolman.io?

Tags: bsc, hd-wallets

I see that Ethereum and Binance smart chain coins are both set to 60 with the same derivation path, So what is that reason? While it seems to be different coins.

[image]

Comment: If you look at https://github.com/satoshilabs/slips/blob/master/slip-0044.md BSC and BNB have different coin types.

Comment: Do you say that the https://iancoleman.ch/ is in the wrong way?

Comment: The official site seems to be https://iancoleman.io/bip39/. I'm pointing to the official BIP44 registry.

Comment: @Ismael same result at your corrected link